# Sorting features in legend

Tags: qgis, polygon, legend

I have a map with a polygon layer containing 100+ features.

I want them to display on the legend and the Layer Tree using the Polygon's ID and then its name i.e: "Id - Name".

I'm using the following steps in QGIS:

```
Symbology -> Categorized -> concat(Id, ' - ', Name).
```

However, after following the above steps they are displayed in the Legend and Layer Tree in this order :

```
1 - Name1
10 - Name10
100 - Name100
101 - Name101
11 - Name11
12 - Name12....
2 - Name2
20 - Name20
3 - Name3
```

So I read that it's sorting them as strings, and I want to know if there is a way to have them sorted by Id while still display like "ID - Name".

Answer (score 7):

You can use `lpad()` function to add zeros (0) on the left side of the ID numbers based on the number of digits that cover the maximum ID number. For example, if the maximum number of digits of the ID number is 3, as in your case (100), then you need to write the following:

```
concat(lpad("ID",3,'0'),' - ',"Name" )
```

In this case the legend will be sorted correctly.

In the following example, I have to convert the `NEW_ID` field from numerical to text, therefore, I used `to_string()` function:

```
concat(lpad(to_string("NEW_ID"),3,'0'),' - ',"Name" )
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

It is also sorted correctly in print composer:

[image: Output_in_Print_Composer]